# Problemas con Formulario de Login

Tags: php, login

Tengo un problema y espero puedan ayudarme, pasa lo siguiente

Hice una página web en Wordpress y por cuestiones de practicidad hicimos un formulario de registro manualmente para algunos campos que requeriamos, el problema viene a la hora del Login necesito revisar dos bases de datos diferentes para poder hacer el Login pero simplemente NO lo hace;

Lo que hago es que tome un código ya existente en la red, el cual crea una `public function` demominada `checkLogin`, lo que quiero es que después de la primer consulta, haga otra consulta para que obtenga un `meta_value` el cual es el valor **Verificado** o **No Verificado**.

Aquí dejo el codigo, gracias de antemano

```
class LoginForm extends DbConn
{
    public function checkLogin($myusername, $mypassword)
    {
        $conf = new GlobalConf;
        $ip_address = $conf->ip_address;
        $login_timeout = $conf->login_timeout;
        $max_attempts = $conf->max_attempts;
        $timeout_minutes = $conf->timeout_minutes;
        $attcheck = checkAttempts($myusername);
        $curr_attempts = $attcheck['attempts'];

        $datetimeNow = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $oldTime = strtotime($attcheck['lastlogin']);
        $newTime = strtotime($datetimeNow);
        $timeDiff = $newTime - $oldTime;

        try {

            $db = new DbConn;
            $tbl_members = $db->tbl_members;
            $err = '';

        } catch (PDOException $e) {

            $err = "Error: " . $e->getMessage();

        }

        $stmt = $db->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM ".$tbl_members." WHERE user_login = :myusername");
        $stmt->bindParam(':myusername', $myusername);
        $stmt->execute();

        // Gets query result
        $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $nombre = $result['nombre'];
        $user_id = $result['ID'];
        $meta_key = 'verificar';

        $db1=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$db_name);
        $sql1="SELECT * FROM 7eb_usermeta WHERE user_id = $user_id AND meta_key = $meta_key ";
    $result1 = mysqli_query($db1,$sql1);
        $row1=mysqli_fetch_array($result1,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $rowvalue = $row1["meta_value"];
```

Comment: ¿Y qué es lo que no funciona? Y también quisiera saber por qué usas por una parte PDO y por otra parte MySQLi? ¿Por qué en una parte usas consultas preparadas y en otra no? ¿Por qué no unificas el código, optando por PDO?

Comment: Pregunto lo mismo que @A.Cedano. Quiero creer que el desorden en el código es porque has mezclado recursos de distintas partes (como mencionaste en tu explicación de arriba), pero sería bueno que lo ordenaras, sea eligiendo una sola librería con la cual comunicarte con la BD (mysqli o PDO), como organizando la lógica, ya que por ejemplo, tienes un `try` para obtener tu `$db`, pero luego accedes al `$db` desde fuera del `try`, ignorando el `catch`, etc... Creo que ordenando tu código puede que se te haga más fácil la depuración, ergo, encontrar en qué parte te falla (si es que te falla...).

Comment: Creo que me ha servido para darme una idea de que estoy haciendo mal, muchas gracias corrijo y les cuento si funciono